# How do you create Login page via URL request in Objective C in Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, authentication, urlrequest

I am making an attempt to create a login after doing some research, but my following code doesn't seem to legitimately have a user signed and keep track of his information once he logs in and keep the user logged in until logged out.

If anyone can verify if it's properly implemented as a login page should and provide some guidance as to how to properly create a login page with my code, I would greatly appreciate it.

Once a user enters in a username (emailTF) and a password (passwordTF) in the textfields and click the sign in button, it triggers the following action:

```
- (IBAction)signIn:(id)sender {

[self sendSignIn:nil success:^(NSArray  * response) {
    NSLog(@"-----------------------------SIGN UP SUCCESS--------------------------");

} failure:^(NSError * error) {
           NSLog(@"************************************Error*********************************");
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Please confirm your username/or password" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
}];
}
```

Once it is successful, it calls the method 'sendSignIn':

```
-(void)sendSignIn:(NSDictionary *)params success:(Success)success failure:(Error)failure

//If email or password textfield is empty, throw up an error sign
{if([_emailTF.text isEqualToString:@""]|| [_passwordTF.text isEqualToString:@""])
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Please input your email or password first" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
}
else
{
    NSString *email = self.emailTF.text;
    NSString *password = self.passwordTF.text;
    NSString *deviceType = @"ios";
    NSString *channelID = [UAirship push].channelID;

    NSDictionary *dict = @{@"email": email, @"password": password, @"deviceType": deviceType, @"channelID": channelID};

//Request to url for example: #define SERVER_URL                          @"http://exampleurl.com"
#define COURSES                             @"/login"

    NSString * url = [SERVER_URL stringByAppendingString:COURSES];
    NSLog(@"REQUEST : %@",url);

    [self.manager POST:url parameters:dict progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull downloadProgress) {

        //Upon success, login the user and segue to home page via 'login' segue
    } success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"login" sender:self];
        success(responseObject);

//Upon failure, throw up a failure sign
        } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
            failure(error);

        }];
    }
}
```

EDIT (How new user is stored - Sign up page):

```
-(AFHTTPSessionManager *)manager{

    if(!_manager){

        _manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    }
    return _manager;
}

- (void)sendSignUp:(NSDictionary *)params success:(Success)success failure:(Error)failure
{
    NSString *firstName = self.firstName.text;
    NSString *lastName = self.lastName.text;
    NSString *email = self.emailTF.text;
    NSString *password = self.passwordTF.text;
    BOOL isProfessor = NO;

    NSString * url = [SERVER_URL stringByAppendingString:COURSES];
    NSLog(@"REQUEST : %@",url);

    NSDictionary *dict = @{@"firstName":firstName,@"lastName":lastName, @"email": email, @"password": password, @"isProfessor": [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]};
    //NSDictionary *dict = @{@"student": @1,@"course":@1, @"section": @1, @"quiz": @1, @"question": @1, @"answer": @1};

    [self.manager POST:url parameters:dict progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull downloadProgress) {


    } success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {

        success(responseObject);

    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {

        failure(error);

    }];

}
```

Comment: @Lulylulu This doesn't update once a user logs in

Comment: @dirkgroten This doesn't update once a user logs in

Comment: Where do you save the credentials? You could have after success a valid token to add...

Comment: @Larme Hi. I've provided how new user is saved in the Edit section above.

Comment: What you exactly want? are you asking that how to locally save user's credential after successfully registration or login?

Comment: @Lion Hello. For the login page, I want to check if the user's entered credential (username and password) matches any credentials (check if the same username and password exist) stored in the URL, http request is made to, and if they do exist, allow the user to login and stay logged in until logged out, and store any saved info during the app session with the logged in user.

Comment: This you can do from your api or webservice's response. You are passing username and password then what you get in response ? You should got true or false status so you can check whether user is valid or not.

Comment: @Lion [self.manager POST:url parameters:dict progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull downloadProgress) wouldn't that be the response? Also by doing POST, how is it checking through all credentials to see if they match the entered username and password in textfields?

Answer (score 0):

Login General scenario :

You should send required `parameters (username,password)` in `json` format to server at given url.

Server side they check that is it valid credential? if yes then it returns ye or true and if no then it returns no or false which you got in your `responseObject`.

According to this response object you came to know that is it valid or not. if you return `true` then allow user for forward stuff. If not `false` then show alert message and don't allow to go forward.

If you want to local storage for validation then store username and password in `NSUserdefaults`. It will remain permanent in your app until you update it or delete it. And you can check with local storage when user enter username and password. and remain sync with server when got internet connectivity.

Hope this will help :)

Update :

According to your comment you can use `NSUserdefault` like,

If you want to store string then,

```
NSString *valueToSave = @"someValue";
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:valueToSave forKey:@"preferenceName"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

to get it back later

```
NSString *savedValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
stringForKey:@"preferenceName"];
```

like this way you can store `NSArray`, `NSDictionary` etc. :)

Comment: I am passing the parameters correctly, and would you consider returned responseObject as validating credential? Also could you guide me to how to implement NSUserdefaults according to my code? Thanks!

Comment: I have updated my answer that mentioned how to use `NSUserdefault` and yes responseObject should have answer that username and password is valid or not.